# Using a non-numeric ID in a backend component

Tags: component, development, custom-component

In a backend component, I have one table that does not have numeric ID numbers. It is instead indexed on a unique alphanumeric value (think like a list of U.S. territories indexed on abbreviation, e.g. 'AZ'). I am working on building a simple view to display and edit these records, but Joomla! strips off the non-numeric ID numbers, removing the "id=" part of the query string altogether when I attempt to edit a record. Where in the system does this occur and can we safely override it?

Comment: It's your router file where this happens. check and fix router.php file.

Comment: If he is doing this in the back end it has nothing to do with the router file since no routing is taking place.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here:

1) Easiest is to create a new auto increment field in your table and use that ID for your editing layout.

2) In your list view create a link that goes to the editing layout and rely on that link for getting to the editing screen.
 (example: index.php?option=**my_component**&view=**my_view**&layout=edit&**my_alpha_id=123ABC**&task=**my_view**.edit)

Be sure if you go the link route that you add the task URL Param to keep from getting errors. Also change the bold sections above to meet your needs.